# Magento change order number length

Tags: magento

How do I change length of order number after I already installed Magento and received some orders.

By default, order number is a 9-digit string, I want to shorten it to maybe 7 or 6 digits.

I read the post below, but looks like it only works for Magento 1.6, in 1.9, database schema has already changed, so there is not a “increment_pad_length” record in the “eav_entity_type” table any more.

https://www.classyllama.com/blog/shortening-increment-id-length-for-orders-invoices-and-shipments

Help! Please

Answer (score 1):

Please run following two queries:

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_type` SET `increment_pad_length` = 2 WHERE `entity_type_code` = ‘order’ LIMIT 1;
UPDATE `eav_entity_store` SET `increment_last_id` = ’109′ WHERE `entity_store_id` = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check one more time. I have 1.9.2 installation and I have this field:[image]

Comment: My bad, I thought it was a record. Thank you.